# RecordLinkage package in R - add weight to individual linking variables

Tags: r, linkage, record-linkage

I'm following the excellent tutorial on [RPubs](http://rpubs.com/ahmademad/RecordLinkage) which uses the magnificent RecordLinkage package. I'm applying this to my own data but I'll just use the tutorial to explain my problem.

In the two datasets for comparison there are a number of common fields used in the linkage:

```
patents <- patents[,c("seq", "firstname", "lastname", "city", "state", "organization")]

nsf <- nsf[, c("InvestigatorId", "FirstName", "LastName", "CityName", "StateCode", "Name")]

names(nsf) <- names(patents)
```

These fields are then compared using the compare.linkage() function:

```
a <- compare.linkage(nsf, patents, blockfld = c("state"), strcmp = T, exclude=c(1))
```

This creates a large RecLinkData object called 'a' that contains a bunch of comparison pairs.

The next step is calculating the M and U weights (agreement weights) using the expectation maximisation (EM) algorithm:

```
b <- emWeights(a, cutoff = 0.8)
```

I think this is basically creating an overall agreement weight which is a product of all the individual linking variables.

My question is how can I add importance for one of the individual linking variables?

So for example, I might know that the "lastname" field is reliable and accurate in both datasets, so if the lastname agreed exactly then to give this more weight in the overall agreement score.

Even some pointers on where to look would be helpful, I'm a bit lost on this and don't even know what to attempt in terms of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't input additional information to `emWeights()`, except maybe `cutoff =`, which accepts a single value or a vector with the same length as the number of attributes. So you can choose a high `cutoff` value for attributes you know to be accurate, so the number of random matches will be minimized.

Apart from that, the EM algorithm in RecordLinkage allows no further customization.

There is however the `epiWeights()` pendant which calculates weights between `0`and `1` using an estimated error rate (default `e= 0.01`) and the average frequencies of values in each field `(1/length(unique(all_values_in_a_field))`. You can supply both to the function manually and this way tweaking the results.

Consider this example:

```
t1 <- data.frame(Vorname = c("Karl", "Fritz"), Name = c("Meister", "Schulz"), stringsAsFactors = F)

t2 <- data.frame(Vorname = c("Karl", "Fritz"), Name = c("Meister", "Schulze"), stringsAsFactors = F)

> epiWeights(linkage)$Wdata  # e = 0.01
[1] 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.3855691

> epiWeights(linkage, e = c(0.01, 0.3)$Wdata  
[1] 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.3120078
```

If you assume a higher error rate for field `Nachname` it gets lower weights.